# Large amount of data in a block

Tags: xsl-fo

XSL-FO document using an XML data source.  One tag has a large amount of data in it (10k+ characters, 200+ lines).  Need to break it across multiple pages.

I've tried keep-together.within-page="auto" which did no good since it's a single block.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.1" xmlns:saxon="http://icl.com/saxon" extension-element-prefixes="saxon" xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="YY">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="Courier">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <!--Page 1 Pagemaster -->
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pagemaster1" page-height="792pt" page-width="612pt">
                <fo:region-body margin-left="15pt" margin-top="10pt" margin-bottom="20pt" margin-right="15pt"/>
                <fo:region-before extent="20pt"/>
                <fo:region-after extent="20pt"/>
                <fo:region-start extent="15pt"/>
                <fo:region-end extent="15pt"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <!-- Page 1 Setup -->
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pagemaster1">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="582pt"/>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell column-number="1" text-align="left" padding-left="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                                <fo:block  linefeed-treatment="preserve" font-size="9pt">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="//YY/FIELD"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:static-content>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<!-- End of Stylesheet -->
```

Output pdf stops at one page, cutting off the balance.  Just need the block to continue on as many pages as necessary in order to display the entire contents.

Comment: you state "Need to break it across multiple pages." then do nothing. put the content into an fo:block and the formatter will break it automatically across pages. You certainly do NOT want keep-together attribute which you state in your question but do not show in your sample content.

Comment: Yes -- I've tried the "do nothing" approach.  The barebones fo:block above cuts off the document at one page.

Comment: You need to show more of your fo then. It sounds like your block is inside a block container that is a absolutely positioned

Comment: Edited post to include entire file.

Comment: You are placing all the content according to your post into the fo:static-content ... essentially putting all the content in the header. You have no fo:flow. What XSL FO engine formats this without an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not understanding the structure of XSL FO. You put static content into the static area (think header and footer) on the page. You put flowing content in a flow.

While you are showing XSL and we have no idea what the returns, use the below as inspiration. You will see it flow across pages because the content is inside the flow area:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="Courier">
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <!--Page 1 Pagemaster -->
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="pagemaster1" page-height="792pt" page-width="612pt">
        <fo:region-body margin-left="15pt" margin-top="10pt" margin-bottom="20pt" margin-right="15pt"/>
        <fo:region-before extent="20pt"/>
        <fo:region-after extent="20pt"/>
        <fo:region-start extent="15pt"/>
        <fo:region-end extent="15pt"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<!-- Page 1 Setup -->
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="pagemaster1">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
        <fo:table>
            <fo:table-column column-width="582pt"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell column-number="1" text-align="left" padding-left="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                        <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" font-size="9pt"> I am the header </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" font-size="20pt"> Heading level 2 Laoreet imperdiet veniam diam stet eirmod diam diam consectetuer tempor rebum sit amet. Odio exerci takimata labore hendrerit tincidunt dolores vulputate dolores duo kasd consequat commodo veniam. Takimata odio dolor te wisi sit clita no ipsum. Takimata aliquyam sed est et lorem nonummy nisl in. Elitr ipsum erat ipsum. Heading level 3 Ut eu ea voluptua dolor sea lobortis dolor euismod illum clita clita. At feugait duo no in ut amet laoreet justo. Eum minim consetetur gubergren consequat illum no ipsum et accusam invidunt et nobis ad accusam eu. Iusto accumsan nulla. Dolore consetetur sea no ut sea eirmod voluptua labore consetetur lorem elit aliquyam blandit et. Lorem tempor lorem et consectetuer aliquyam aliquyam augue no sadipscing invidunt ullamcorper stet invidunt takimata et velit. Sanctus voluptua invidunt. Ipsum vero lorem voluptua duis dolor magna. Est consetetur elitr et blandit labore ut dolore blandit dolor stet stet accusam. Heading Level 4 Sit delenit ipsum tempor tempor amet dolor minim vero dolores wisi justo erat stet sanctus magna labore eos ut. Erat rebum accusam vel iusto et. Lorem eu elitr placerat quod vel diam ipsum duis amet sadipscing feugiat sanctus sea amet. Voluptua lorem molestie laoreet clita magna rebum sed magna minim est magna eirmod sadipscing magna labore nibh eirmod. Et dolore in. At diam consetetur gubergren rebum ullamcorper lorem est delenit sed sit iriure consectetuer nonumy velit et duo et. Kasd magna nonumy labore ea ex dolor gubergren sit volutpat gubergren duo invidunt ex. Nulla sit diam magna lorem justo. Sea placerat te at ipsum sed clita invidunt dolores aliquyam dolores et et amet volutpat. Feugiat sed tation duis dolor tempor esse facilisis no no diam. Lorem consetetur et et clita amet eos ad dolore diam. Heading Level 5 Ipsum et consequat erat amet lorem et nulla tempor amet praesent nonumy sea nonumy sea lorem dolor. Molestie dolores ea adipiscing et eos autem sit hendrerit et accusam lorem amet vulputate ex ut luptatum tempor. Ullamcorper erat sanctus sit dolor exerci vero amet tempor hendrerit vero voluptua assum nulla feugait tincidunt. Tincidunt invidunt dolore ut dolore option. Ut id et amet aliquyam ullamcorper est laoreet et ipsum. Invidunt erat accusam ullamcorper justo vero eum dolore no kasd sed commodo ut takimata clita. Diam lorem est ad feugiat. Heading Level 6 Iriure odio in et magna amet. Volutpat vero diam vulputate. Sit dolore justo ut nibh magna lobortis dolor. Consetetur elitr dolor invidunt duo gubergren sed eos wisi ex et vero aliquyam voluptua ut. Elitr et duo et nulla et sit et dignissim dolor et no dolore dolor consequat eos takimata placerat. Euismod labore dolor rebum vel no. Sea consequat ex amet takimata sanctus et diam ea dolore et. </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Result showing content in two pages (sorry not pretty just showing what you want):

[image]

Comment: Perfection!  Got it sorted now! This is what happens when a DBA gets thrown into a different language...